# Docusign recipient ID Check/Authentication

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We use Docusign within our Salesforce instance, we have a couple of different options when selecting Recipient ID verification, SMS, Knowledge based, etc..My question is where would I tell Docusign to default on a specific authentication process.

For example. Say I click a Docusign Status  button on the opportunity, it automatically brings in the recipient from set as the primary contact of the opportunity, and uses the CEM ,subject etc... from Docusign. Where can I if anyplace, dictate to have an ID verification method on?

Answer (score 0):

Called Docusign Support, Apparently the only parameters you can pass into the button is  for the SMS Verification  and the Code Verification. The KBA authentication is not supported yet.